# get count from related table data in django rest framework

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two tables

```
class student(models.Model):
    frist_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class subject(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(student)
    sub_name = models.CharField()
```

I want student list and subject count in serializer

my serializer

```
classs SubjectSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobPosting
        fields = ('id','sub_name')

class StudentSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = SubjectSerializers(source = 'student')
    class Meta:
        model = JobPosting
        fields = ('id','first_name', 'last_name','sub')
```

How can i get subject count for every student in serializer,  Now i am geting subject table data but i want count like this

```
"detail": [{
        "id": 680,
        "first_name": "riya",
        "last_name": "tri",
        "subject_count": 5
      }],
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a [serializer method field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Then StudentSerializer becomes the following:

```
class StudentSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = SubjectSerializers(source = 'student')
    subject_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = JobPosting
        fields = ('id','first_name', 'last_name','sub')

    def get_subject_count(self, student):
        return Subject.objects.filter(student=student).count()
```

Comment: What would the performance implications of this be? Wouldn't this perform a separate query for each JobPosting object?